# WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 APIMgtGatewayJWTGeneratorImpl Claims

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

1. Upgraded WSO2 APIM from version 3.1.0 to 4.1.0
2. Added new claims by navigating to -> Add New Claim as shown below.
   [image]
   [image]
3. Published the microservice
4. Invoke the token endpoint with created OIDC scope
5. Invoke the api endpoint by passing access_token
6. When i hit an API with the bearer token, i am getting the X-JWT-Assertion header in the carbon logs but when i decode it, it doesn't contain the claims that i added in local claims.
7. The APIMgtGatewayJWTGeneratorImpl return only the below claims not all the expected claims.
   [image]
8. Why APIMgtGatewayJWTGeneratorImpl returns only limited claims?
9. Is there any configuration required to return newly added claims?
10. Do we need to write custom JWTGenerator to return all the claims?

**Expectations**

- The JWT Token should have all the claims that i added in local claims.

**Environment**

- WSO2 APIM 4.1.0
- WSO2 IS 5.11.0

Answer (score 0):

You can verify whether the access token contains the required claims. If the claims are present in the access token, then the gateway copies the claims to the backend jwt. You don’t need to write any extensions here. As the gateway self validates the access tokens, there is no way to get these claims unless those come via the access token.

**Update:** Please follow the following steps.

1. Create an application in the devportal.
2. When you generate consumer key and secret in the devportal for this application, it creates the service provider underneath. This service provider will be available when you logged into the carbon console.
3. Click on the service provider and configure the claims under claim configuration. You can provide the required claims here as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

4. Update the user profile as in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/identity-lifecycles/update-profile/
5. Use the openid scope when generating the access token.

> curl -k -X POST https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token -d
> "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=openid" -H
> "Authorization: Basic Base64Encoded(ck:cs)"

6. When the gateway generates the backend jwt, it adds the claims from the access token.

Comment: verified that access token contains only the basic default claims only. The required claims are not present in the access token. Is there any configuration to set the required claims to the access token?